# No autocomplete in interactive python

Tags: python, elpy, autocompletion

OS: Windows 10
Emacs: 28.2
Python: 3.10
Package: elpy
My init.el:

```
...
(elpy-enable)

;; Use IPython for REPL
(setq python-shell-interpreter "jupyter"
  python-shell-interpreter-args "console --simple-prompt"
  python-shell-prompt-detect-failure-warning nil)
(add-to-list 'python-shell-completion-native-disabled-interpreters
         "jupyter")
```

Issue: open a .py file, press C-c C-c, elpy creates *python* buffer and sends code in current buffer to there successfully. However, there is no autocomplete in *python* interactive buffer. If input some characters and press "Tab" key, "no match" displays in echo area. If input a class name and a dot, such as "foo.", nothing happens.

Autocomplete works fine in python file with Python major mode.